# Making players switch sides

Tags: xbox-360, pro-evolution-soccer-2010

My Master League team has 2 good left backs, and no good right backs. Is there a way I can train one of them to play on the right? (At the moment, they both suck in that position). Do I up their athletic ability training? I don't seem to be able to get them to retrain for that position, since they already have SB...

Comment: What version are you referring to? 2012?

Comment: @soulstriderx from the date I asked the question, you can probably work this one out yourself...

Comment: Could still be a version prior to pes 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head (I've not played Pro Evo in a couple of years) I don't remember it being possible to change a player's side as it is their natural-footedness that the R/L represents.

The only way I reckon you'd be able to do that is if you can still edit players individually via the game's editor?  You could use this to boost your player's **Weak Foot Accuracy** (set it to 8 or more) and **Weak Foot Frequency**.  Even then, if you make changes, it may not be possible to add them in to your existing Master League since the game's already underway.

Comment: Yep, I agree, editor is the way.

Comment: The question is asking about master league training to do this. If I could edit my players, there would be no question.